# How to add extended properties for a particular attendee

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a list of attendees to an event, and I want to show different information depending on the attendee. How can I add extended properties for each individual copy of the event for each attendee.

Answer (score 0):

An [event resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) contains a list of attendees.

```
"attendees": [
    {
      "id": string,
      "email": string,
      "displayName": string,
      "organizer": boolean,
      "self": boolean,
      "resource": boolean,
      "optional": boolean,
      "responseStatus": string,
      "comment": string,
      "additionalGuests": integer
    }
  ],
```

Extend properties on event

Currently it is only possible to [extend properties](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/extended-properties#adding_and_updating) on an event not on the attendees of the event.

```
{
  "extendedProperties": {
    "private": {
      "petsAllowed": "yes"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer you cant add extended properties to an attendee of an event.